# Migrating Data to Google Cloud

Tags: wordpress, ftp, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, sftp

I recently bought Google Cloud services and want to migrate my wordpress website from my current hosting service (which uses CPanel) to Google Cloud. I already have a project and instance created on Google Cloud but I can't seem to understand how to connect it with FTP or through webUI so that I can upload my already existing web files.

Comment: Have you also installed LAMP stack on instance? Can you share information about instance and what OS you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use a plugin for migrating your WordPress website. For example: https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Comment: It doesn't have option to migrate to Google Cloud

Comment: Well it should support all servers and platforms. Its a very popular plugin. You should read the documentation on how to use the plugin: https://snapcreek.com/duplicator/docs/quick-start/#quick-040-q